# How 'random' is allocation of memory when I say “new Integer” in Java?

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, garbage-collection, jvm

I am asking this question again as my earlier attempt did not succeed due to language ambiguity at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19115526/how-random-is-allocation-of-memory-when-i-say-new-int-in-java.

Which random number generators, if any, does a JVM use for determining allocation address when allocating a memory block for a variable when it runs the bytecode corresponding to 'new Integer'?

Comment: You've just asked the exact same question...Also, there is no `new int()` in Java.

Comment: Allocation is not random at all.

Comment: Allocation follows an algorithm.

Comment: Please note that SO moderator users (including me) have been reviewing your question. If it is still on hold, it means that someone deemed it to be off topic anyway...

Comment: @Cruncher: What algorithms are used?

Comment: @Zafar That's up to the JVM to decide I think

Comment: @Stefano Sanfilippo: What should be done? Should I remove this question?

Comment: @Zafar: sometimes you can turn the question round. How would you do it? How would you get around memory defragmentation? You'll conclude rather quickly that a random scheme would be suboptimal.

Comment: Since this one is getting answered right now, I suggest removing the old one. For the future, note that when questions are put on hold, they are filed for a review by moderators, who have the ability to cast a vote and either reopen it or leave it closed. It's no use reposting.

Comment: Anyway, memory management is still a field of research and it's not at all random! For instance, read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allocation_algorithms or look on the Internet for more specific resources.

Comment: Thanks:) Will keep in mind.

Comment: @Sotirios: The earlier question was edited in desperation for finding a relevant answer. This question was posted and it succeeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What algorithms are used?

Java uses TLAB (Thread Local Allocation Buffers) for "normal" sized objects.  This means each thread grab some Eden space and turns this grab of memory into individual objects.  Thus small objects are typically sequential in memory for that thread, except if a new chunk of memory needs to be grabbed.

Large objects such as large arrays are allocated directly into tenured space, finding a free space which is enough for object allocated (in a single threaded manner)

> Which random number generators, if any, does a JVM use for determining allocation address when allocating a memory block

It doesn't use any random number generators for allocation.  Nor would you want it to.  It would be much slower and add needless complexity.

> for a variable, e.g. int a;

Variables are not allocated only Objects are allocated.  Variables can appear on the stack or in an objects and are usually laid out in the simplest manner possible.

> when it runs the bytecode corresponding to 'new int()'?

You can't do `new int()`

---

BTW: There is a common misconception that if you print a `new Object()` and get something like `Object@b7f86352` that the hexidecimal is an address.  This is not the case.  The address of the object can be used as a seed for a random number generated and stored in the header, but this number has nothing to do with the actual memory address and it doesn't change as the object is moved around in memory.

Comment: When I say 
int a;
 or 
new int
what happens? Doesn't the JVM pick a random address from the available memory pool and allocate it?

Comment: @Zafar The answers are in the answer. ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I get some idea what happens.

Comment: @Zafar When you say "new int" you should get a syntax error message from the compiler.

Comment: @Patricia: Yes, it was my mistake. It should have been new Integer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no random generation involved. Simply the JVM chooses where to place your `int` based on criteria that make it hard if not impossible to predict its location without inspecting the internal state of the memory allocator. In that sense it is "random".

Comment: Do you have any idea what that criteria might be?

Comment: @Zafar The criteria is that you shouldn't need to know so it is hidden from you.

Comment: Why is it hidden from us?

Comment: It is not hidden, you just have to read the JVM sources. What Peter meant is to not rely on a specific behaviour, because it is an internal detail and it might between JDK releases

Comment: Isn't it done for security so that we can't predict exactly where a memory chunk is allocated?

Comment: It could be done in principle, but I don't think common implementation do it.

Comment: @Nicola: Well I don't know about JVM, but OSs have it, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization which I discovered only a few minutes ago through StackOverflow.

Comment: @Zafar The OS hides the executable code from the attacker using randomization. In Java objects, there's no executable code and it can't be jumped to, so there's no need for such a randomization. The reason why there's a randomly looking number in the object header is that it gets used as `Object#hashCode`, which should be nicely distributed. It may or may not be based on the address of the object when it was created.